# Build cannot be found when publishing results to TFS

Tags: c#, tfs, microsoft-test-manager

I'm attempting to publish test results to Microsoft Test Manager through TFS but I'm getting the following error when attempting to publish results through the TFS API:

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestObjectNotFoundException:
Build vstfs:///Build/Build/### cannot be found.
```

I'm getting my test plan and creating a test run [the way Microsoft suggests](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7ae33517-5811-486e-bab2-261ab9d18f89/createtestrun-api?forum=vsmantest):

```
plan = teamProject.TestPlans.Query(
    "SELECT * FROM TestPlan WHERE PlanName = '" + planName + "')[0];
ITestRun run = plan.CreateTestRun(true);
run.AddTestPoints(testPoints, null);
run.Save();
```

So why is it saying the build can't be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Builds are periodically cleared out of the system so you may want to be sure you're [using the latest build](http://www.woodwardweb.com/dotnet/tfs_build_api_b_1.html). You can then get the latest builds URI and associate it with your run.

```
Uri GetLatestBuildURI(string projectName) {
    Uri buildUri = null;
    IBuildServer buildServer = _tfs.GetService<IBuildServer>();
    IBuildDetailSpec detailSpec = buildServer.CreateBuildDetailSpec(projectName);
    detailSpec.MaxBuildsPerDefinition = 1;
    detailSpec.QueryOrder = BuildQueryOrder.FinishTimeDescending;
    IBuildQueryResult results = buildServer.QueryBuilds(detailSpec);
    if (results.Builds.Length == 1) {
        IBuildDetail detail = results.Builds[0];
        buildUri = detail.Uri;
    }
    return buildUri;
}
```

...

```
ITestRun run = plan.CreateTestRun(true);
run.BuildUri = GetLatestBuildURI(projectName);
run.AddTestPoints(testPoints, null);
run.Save();
```